# Node.js doesn't serve more than 5 browser tabs

Tags: node.js, apache

I am using Apache, Mysql and Node.js to run a dynamic website which uses the long polling to update the content.

The main language is PHP but for updating the content I use Node.js

I run the **Node.js** server on port **9000**

**Apache** is running on port **80**

I am proxying any request arrives to Apache (to the Node.js site) to port 9000, below is the sites-available portion for the website (www.example.com):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    .
    .
    ProxyPass /node  http://localhost:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse /node  http://localhost:9000/
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
```

The Node.js website: www.example.com/node/

I noticed that **Node.js can't serve more than 5 browser tabs**! It stops updating after that. I read that Node.js can serve thousand of connections! How can I achieve the high performance?

The Node.js is communicating with Mysql direct every 2 seconds to check for updates.

Shall I use **Nginx** instead of Apache? Running both Webserver and Node.js on **port 80** is healthy? What is the best way/services to use? Please advise and many thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using? There might be a limit on the number of connections to a given host.

Comment: @tadman I am using IE and Chrome and both have same problem. I don't think it is a browser problem.

Comment: It stops updating any tab created after the 5th, or it stops updating all tabs after a 6th is added?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin if I open the tab #6, then none of the opened tab is updated. So the answer it stops updating all tabs after a 6th is added.

Comment: What happens if you connect your browser directly to port 9000? Just to eliminate complexity here and isolate the problem. NodeJS can handle a lot more than 5 connections.

Comment: @tadman Do you think that it is possible to run two applications on same port? I will try that and get back to you asap. But it is important to me to run the node.js and webserver on port 80 because I don't want to show the clients another port. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I noticed that Node.js can't serve more than 5 browser tabs! It stops updating after that. I read that Node.js can serve thousand of connections! How can I achieve the high performance?

You are getting confused. Web browsers have a maximum number of concurrent connections they will open to a given server ("origin").

You cannot accurately test concurrency with a single browser. Try load testing tools like [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) or [apache bench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html).

To quickly prove this, open multiple distinct **browsers** (chrome, firefox, IE, etc), and a few tabs in each browser and that should illustrate what is going on here.

Comment: I will check that and get back to you here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You would also need to check your Apache configuration to help figure out why so few connections can be made. Depending on your configuration (such as using the Apache `mpm-prefork` module), you might only have 5 slots that Apache could have as possible connections - particularly on a development system.

Apache, with Mod-PHP is frequently setup on Apache with a forking model. On Ubuntu, for example, you can check in the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` directory, and see what `mpm*.conf` and `mpm*.load` systems are being used.

Long term, NginX will usually be a better host, and certainly for large number of connections.

Comment: I will check that and get back to you here. Thank you very much.